# Whats the Angular way of displaying alert messages such as Invalid login?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
login_app.factory('login_service', function ($http) {                                                                                                                               
    return {                                                                                                                                                                        
        login: function (user,pass) {                                                                                                                                               
            //return the promise directly.                                                                                                                                          
            return $http({                                                                                                                                                          
                          url:"/service/login",                                                                                                                                     
                          method:"POST",                                                                                                                                            
                          data:JSON.stringify({username:user,password:pass})                                                                                                        

                          }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {                                                                                                     
                                // assign  $scope.persons here                                                                                                                      
                              // as promise is resolved here                                                                                                                        
                                localStorage.setItem("auth_token",headers("X-Auth-Token"));                                                                                         
                                window.location = "/layout/dashboard"                                                                                                               
                           }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {                                                                                                      

                                // If I have a custom alert box, should I display it from
                                // or I should use a directive for bootstrap alert-box.
                                // But what should I do here so that Alertbox knows it is


                          });                                                                                                                                                       
        }                                                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                                               
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot ways and everyone uses proper according to their needs.

I would put bootstrap alerts into Dialog:

[image]

Demo <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vQXtQ7BC6oB8i58s9lK0?p=preview)**</kbd>